# Uploading Expo App to Google Play Console

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console

I am trying to upload my expo app to google play console. When I try to upload my build I get an error in the console: Your app currently targets API level 28 and must target at least API level 29 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 29.

What can I do to change this and upload app bundles again?
I tried adding to my app.json: "sdkVersion": "37.0.0"

Still the same error....

Comment: you have to upgrade your expo version using `expo upgrade`. https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-37-is-now-available-69g

Comment: in my package.json I have: "expo": "^38.0.0" after using 'expo upgrade'
I still get the same error while uploading to google play console after building as an app bundle

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: I got it working with version 38.0.8